# Close navigation when navigation item is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is for my hamburger menu to close when an item is clicked inside of it. As of right now, the menu only uses html and css.

The difference between this nav bar and others is that mine is created from a input checkbox html element, what i need is for my checkbox to uncheck when a link is clicked inside of the hamburger. This should close the entire menu just like it would if i clicked on the hamburger. Also, could you explain what and why the javascript does what it does, i don't have much experience with javascript, thanks. :)

I also made the checkbox visible just so that we can have a better understanding of whats going on.

My CSS:

```css
/* navigation menu */
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 10000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaeb;

}

.menu {
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

/* link items */
.menu a {
  clear: right;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #33334d;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #c2c2d6;
}

/* hamburger properties */
label {
  float: right;
  display: none;
  width: 26px;
  line-height: 70px;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 36px;
}

/* checkbox */
#toggle {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1075px) {

/* hamburger properties */
  label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

/* nav menu properties */
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
  }

/* link items */
  .menu a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaeb;
  }

/* makes links show when checkbox is checked */
  #toggle:checked + .menu {
    display: block;
  }
}


My HTML:
```

```html
  <div class="nav">
      <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">example</a>
        <a href="#">example</a>
        <a href="#">example</a>
        <a href="#">example</a>
        <a href="#">example</a>
        <a href="#">example</a>
        <a href="#">example</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, interesting. It's a pretty weird practise, what you have, but it could work. You can make menu show/hide by input checked. Very interesting. I have never think of like that.

But also you will need a piece of JS code.

By CSS you can handle some basic selector like :hover, :focus, :active etc. In our your case you also make some interesting click event. But checkbox is not for that purpose.

Click and other event are handled by JS (more https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp).

So in our case, we select all links:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.menu a');
```

then we have to add click event to every link, which will set our input to `checked="false"` = close menu.

This JS code will only work, when selected links are rendered, so you need to put this piece of code to the end of your html file before `</body>` or use `window.onload`...

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.menu a');
var linksLength = links.length

for(var i = 0; i < linksLength; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('toggle').checked = false;
  });
}
```

```css
/* navigation menu */
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 10000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaeb;

}

.menu {
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

/* link items */
.menu a {
  clear: right;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #33334d;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #c2c2d6;
}

/* hamburger properties */
label {
  float: right;
  display: none;
  width: 26px;
  line-height: 70px;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 36px;
}

/* checkbox */
#toggle {
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1075px) {

/* hamburger properties */
  label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

/* nav menu properties */
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
  }

/* link items */
  .menu a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaeb;
  }

/* makes links show when checkbox is checked */
  #toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  #toggle:checked + .menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="nav" for="toggle">
  <div class="icon">&#9776;</div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#">example</a>
    <a href="#">example</a>
    <a href="#">example</a>
    <a href="#">example</a>
    <a href="#">example</a>
    <a href="#">example</a>
    <a href="#">example</a>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: This works! The only small problem i have now is that i can click anywhere on the white area near the hamburger and it'll open the nav. I want it to only be opened when the hamburger is clicked.

Comment: You can set nav for width and height like hamburger and then .menu will have position: absolute to the hamburger - .nav (position: relative, width: 20px height: 20px), .menu (position: absolute; top: 100%; right: 0; width: 100%;), that could work. Or you will remove checkbox and add another click event to open the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Javscript may not actually be required, depending on your needs.

If you give the div containing your nav links an ID you can target this with an `a` tag setting the href to the ID. Then you can use the `:target` selector to change the visibility of our navigation div.

```css
/* navigation menu */

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 10000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaeb;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}


/* link items */

.menu a {
  clear: right;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #33334d;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.toggle {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #33334d;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #c2c2d6;
}


/* hamburger properties */

.toggle,
label {
  float: right;
  display: none;
  width: 26px;
  line-height: 70px;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 36px;
}


/* checkbox */

#toggle {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1075px) {
  /* hamburger properties */
  .toggle,
  label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  /* nav menu properties */
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  /* link items */
  .menu a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaeb;
  }
  /* makes links show when checkbox is checked */
  #menu:target,
  #toggle:checked+.menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a class="toggle" href="#menu">&#9776;</a>

  <div class="menu" id="menu">
    <a href="#">example</a>
    <a href="#">example</a>
    <a href="#">example</a>
    <a href="#">example</a>
    <a href="#">example</a>
    <a href="#">example</a>
    <a href="#">example</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked, but i can no longer click on the hamburger icon to manually close the menu! the menu is also open by default